# Issue while fetching mongo data with "Ref" in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Hey i have been trying graphql so there is a situation where i am stuck in "Ref" part... lets suppose i have too schemas as defined below

User.js

```
const userschema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdevents: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Event"
    }
  ]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userschema);
```

and then events.js

```
const eventschema=new Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    creator:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    }
})
module.exports=mongoose.model('Event',eventschema)
```

So when i was working with events data i tried to fetch User properties via the following populate() method

```
events: () => {
        return Event.find().populate('creator').then(result => {
          return result.map(e => {
            return { ...e._doc, _id: e._doc._id.toString() };
          });
        });
      }
```

so i am able to access all the User properties now but what if i need to access events field that is inside "createdevents" in User.js means i need to run once more populate method so that i can get all the events properties stored inside "createdevents" but withing the same code below

In short i need to apply one more populate method here anyhow in

```
 events: () => {
                return Event.find().populate('creator').then(result => {
                  return result.map(e => {
                    return { ...e._doc, _id: e._doc._id.toString() };
                  });
                });
              }
```

so that i can reach one more time in all events properties inside createdevents

The order i need is like

Events(creator) ->used populate (achieved All user properties) ->now in User.js i have to apply populate again to achieve all events properties

Sorry if this sounds weird i am unable to explain it
I think its something like **mutilevel population**

For now if i run the query

```
query{
  events{
    title
    creator{
      _id
      email
      createdevents{
        _id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i get

```
{
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "title": "asd",
        "creator": {
          "_id": "5d64354bfd7bb826a9331948",
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "createdevents": [
            {
              "_id": "5d6435a78150062703df70ff"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5d6435ab8150062703df7101"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5d6435cc8150062703df7102"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

which is fine but i am only able to get _ids of the event i need to get all the properties which can be achieved by populate method i gues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate across multiple levels by:

```
Event.find()
     .populate({
       path: 'creator',
       populate: { path: 'createdevents' }
     });
```

Comment: thanks it worked ! can u pls have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665932/populating-the-ref-in-mongoose-schema-while-working-with-graphql?noredirect=1#comment101780785_57665932 it's something the same issue actually